# How to configure authentication in ASP.NET Core 1.0

Tags: c#, entity-framework, authentication, asp.net-core

I am trying to add authentication to my application, i have entity framework running but now i would like to authenticate the user but i am running into lots of issues configuring it in the configure constructor.

For instance in many tutorials they provide code that no longer works like if I do

```
    // Configure ASP.NET Identity to use our Identity-based application context
    services.AddAuthentication()
        .AddIdentity()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

It tells me that i need to specify the type arguments explicitly, but this is what is in the tutorial?

https://shellmonger.com/2015/05/29/asp-net-mvc5-identity-part-1-the-database/

I am having a hard time understanding what is the right way of doing this, all i want to do is authenticate an user when he/she logs in.

Here is my project.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "EntityFramework.Commands": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "EntityFramework.MicrosoftSqlServer": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "EntityFramework.Core": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics.Entity": "7.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity": "3.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework": "3.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Authorization": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.WebListener": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Framework.CodeGenerators.Mvc": "1.0.0-beta5",
    "Microsoft.Framework.ConfigurationModel.Json": "1.0.0-beta4",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Logging": "1.0.0-beta7",
    "Microsoft.Framework.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-beta8",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink.Loader": "14.0.0-rc1-final"
  },
```

and my configuration :

```
public class Startup
{
    public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; set; }

    public Startup()
    {

        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .AddJsonFile("config.json")
        .AddJsonFile($"config.json", optional: true);
        builder.AddEnvironmentVariables();
        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }
    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    // For more information on how to configure your application, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=398940
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddEntityFramework()
        .AddSqlServer()
        .AddDbContext<OrganizationsAppContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:DefaultConnection:ConnectionString"]));

        // Specify the configuration of our Application database context
        services.Configure<Option>(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultUserName = Configuration.Get("DefaultUser:Username");
            options.DefaultUserPassword = Configuration.Get("DefaultUSer:Password");
        });

        // Configure ASP.NET Identity to use our Identity-based application context
        //services.AddAuthentication()
        //    .AddIdentity()
        //    .AddEntityFrameworkStores()
        //    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();   DOES NOT WORK!

        services.AddMvc();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseIISPlatformHandler();
        app.UseMvc();
        app.UseDefaultFiles();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseIdentity();
    }

    // Entry point for the application.
    public static void Main(string[] args) => WebApplication.Run<Startup>(args);
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, i am running out of ideas, i have tried several other sites with the same result (did this way of doing it change?).

Comment: Do note that ASP.NET Core 1.0 is still not finished. The tutorial seems to be from last May, almost a year ago. A lot has changed since. Try to find a more recent tutorial to help you, preferably from the RC versions that are now out.

Comment: Haven't been able to find, do you have a link you could help me with?, maybe i am searching it wrong. thank you

Comment: Please don't mix package versions, it's calling for trouble. Your project.json is a chaotic mix of rc1-final, beta4, beta5, beta7 and  beta8.

Comment: You can find an example on the official documentation : https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authentication/introduction-to-aspnet-identity.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can configure identity in two ways in RC1:

1- When you are adding Identity

Example:

```
services.AddIdentity<User, Role>(config => {
    // Config here
    config.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
    config.Password = new PasswordOptions
    {
        RequireDigit = true,
        RequireNonLetterOrDigit = false,
        RequireUppercase = false,
        RequireLowercase = true,
        RequiredLength = 8,
    }; 
}).AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationContext, int>() 
  .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

2- Use `IdentityOptions`:

Example:

```
services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.Password = new PasswordOptions
        {
            RequireDigit = true,
            RequireNonLetterOrDigit = false,
            RequireUppercase = false,
            RequireLowercase = true,
            RequiredLength = 8,
        };
        options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents
        {
            OnRedirectToLogin = ctx =>
            {
                ctx.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
                return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
            }
        };
    });
}
```

More info:
[ASP.NET Authentication Doc](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authentication/index.html)