# Asp.net core 1.1 validate security stamp isn't working

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.1, asp.net-core-identity

Ok so i've been struggling with this for 2 days now, and can't find anything about it.

i'm using asp.net core 1.1 and i already implemented the identity in my system and it works great. but my issue is that user stays online after updating the security stamp.

i tried set `SecurityStampValidationInterval` to `zero,1` seconds but it doesn't seem to effect anything.

at this point i'm not really sure if it is a bug? or i'm doing something wrong?

here is how my `IdentityOptions` looks like:

```
services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.Tokens.PasswordResetTokenProvider = _defaultTokenProviderName;

                options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
                options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
                options.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
                options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
                options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;

                options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;

                options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789_.";

                options.SecurityStampValidationInterval = TimeSpan.Zero;



                options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.CookieName = "Identity_cookie";
                options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(1);
                options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.SlidingExpiration = true;

            options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents()
            {
                OnRedirectToLogin = (context) =>
                {
                    var cul = context.HttpContext.Features.Get<IRequestCultureFeature>();
                    var lang = cul.RequestCulture.Culture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName;


                    context.Response.Redirect($"/{lang}/Account/Login?{context.Options.ReturnUrlParameter}" +
                         $"={System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode(context.Request.Path + context.Request.QueryString)}");
                    return Task.FromResult(0);
                },

            };
            });
```

and this is how i update the security stamp:

```
user.Blocked = !user.Blocked;
await _userManager.UpdateSecurityStampAsync(user);
await _userManager.UpdateAsync(user);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It appears you have extended ApplicationUser to add Blocked property?
  Why not set LockoutEnd which should achieve the same result?  Also I would suggest you look at returned IdentityResult for both UpdateSecurityStampAsync & UpdateAsync to ensure Succeeded is true.

Comment: Yes I'm extending `IdentityUser` to add some properties like `DisplayName` `Blocked` `ProfileImage`. The problem with using lockoutEnd as a block factor is that we might use it to lock the account after say 10 wrong trying for 30 minutes or so. So it won't be good to block user's posts based on Lockout status but I'm going to give it a try to see if it has any effect on validating `SecurityStamp`.

Comment: About checking `IdentityResult` both are success and the database values get changed along with `securityStamp`, I even changed it manually to see if it has any effect on the logged in user but nothing. I also tried to remove/change `expireTimeSpan` as well as `SlidimgExpiration` to check if it interfaces with `security stamp validator` but no luck.

Comment: Maybe add `options.OnSecurityStampRefreshingPrincipal = c => { return Task.FromResult(0); };` to services.AddIdentity and set a breakpoint to see if it's getting hit?

Comment: Tried that and from what I remember the breakpoint never get hit. Tried it with and without `expireTimeSpan,SlidingExpiration`. I may try today to update `Microsoft.Aspnetcore.Authentication` to `2 preview` version and see if it has any difference.

Comment: Something not right then, it should be hitting it based on SecurityStampValidationInterval - what happens when you change it to TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1) instead of TimeSpan.Zero?

Comment: I tested with `from seconds 0,1,15,30` and `from minutes 1,5` but none of them seems to do anything

Comment: Is there is any logging for validating security stamp operations I can use?

Comment: The only other thing is to try the other configuration method (option 2) shown here https://stackoverflow.com/a/36593541/310601.  Shouldn't make any difference, but it's worth a shot.

Comment: I did both actually but with no difference :(. `service.config` and inside `addIdentity`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated my question to include the rest of the code (sorry it was under `service.AddIdentity..` so i forgot to copy it).

so my problem was about setting `options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.Events` in order to use custom `OnRedirectToLogin` from identity options for some reason i had to move it to `app.UseCookieAuthentication()`

my new code is:

```
app.UseIdentity();

            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
            {
                Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents()
                {
                    OnRedirectToLogin = (context) =>
                    {
                        var cul = context.HttpContext.Features.Get<IRequestCultureFeature>();
                        var lang = cul.RequestCulture.Culture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName;


                        context.Response.Redirect($"/{lang}/Account/Login?{context.Options.ReturnUrlParameter}" +
                             $"={System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode(context.Request.Path + context.Request.QueryString)}");
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    },

                }
            });
```

and `services.Configure<IdentityOptions>`:

```
options.Tokens.PasswordResetTokenProvider = _defaultTokenProviderName;

                options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
                options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
                options.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
                options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
                options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;

                options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;

                options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789_.";

                options.SecurityStampValidationInterval = TimeSpan.Zero;



                options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.CookieName = "Identity_cookie";
                options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(1);
                options.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.SlidingExpiration = true;
```

i don't know if this is a bug or something but the configuration is suppose to be inside `ConfigureServices`, am i right?

Comment: You should probably tag this w/ asp.net-core-identity or create an issue at https://github.com/aspnet/Identity for a better response.